# Is it correct to use “am” in a sentence without “I”?

Tags: grammaticality, ellipsis, subjects

I am noticing the trend of people using to be (am) without the subject (I). For example:

> Guys, am deciding to move away from Photoshop. Can you advise other apps as alternative?

Is this grammatically correct? I feel like people use this like it’s normal. From what I’ve learned about English in my younger days, I never met this occurrences. So I feel this form is weird and not normal. But is it correct though?

Comment: Well, it's short for "I am." It's not necessarily correct, but you'd probably be understood. Reminds me of telegrams, where you had to pay by the word.

Comment: It's typical of texting/email correspondence. Although it's common and the meaning is clear, it is NOT grammatical. Don't use it in formal writing.

Comment: What is the source? This first of all sounds like a tweet or a group text; it would not be acceptable in formal written English. Second, *am deciding to move away* and *advise other apps as alternative* are also grammatically suspect, and I would guess the author is not a native speaker or else is very careless.